# Matrix completion: How to assign names to the completed columns?

Tags: self-study, inference, matrix

I am wondering if this the right place to ask this question. Normally it should be :).
I am recently reading some papers about [matrix completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_completion) such as in [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~montanar/RESEARCH/FILEPAP/spectral16.pdf), and [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.3150.pdf).

I didn't go through some testing yet, but I am wondering  about the following problem, suppose I have some elements $E_1,E_2,....,E_n$ and suppose that I have information about $m$ elements $E_1,...,E_m$ such as $m < n$.

Suppose that at this stage I applied one of the matrix completion algorithms and I got my $n \times n$ matrix, How to assign labels (names) to the completed columns? 
The problem is that the column order can be arbitrary, so it may be mathematically correct but may have no real meaning if the labels are not assigned correctly.

Comment: What software/language are you using? Also you should provide a bit of code to clarify the question

Comment: The examples I have seem are from some packages, such as this one http://www.convexoptimization.com/wikimization/index.php/Matrix_Completion.m. you need to provide the matrix but the order of the infered columns is the main concern

Comment: Thanks for this interesting post, new to me. At first I thought it wasn't statistical area, but reading some of the papers I've come to a different conclusion. I'm not so certain your particular question is statistical yet, but its an interesting topic.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. Yeah indeed it seems like a interesting topic, it is a kinda of extension to the compressed sensing theory (To substitute smapling Nyquist theorem). I am also new to it. it is a part of a homework .

Comment: @sirus You say "it is a part of a homework". In that case, please add the `homework` tag

Comment: I think I was a bit confused when I asked the question. In fact for matrix completition we know the order of the rows and columns and we have a uniform random sampler that takes small set of elements $m << n^{2}$ and then we use these algorithms to try to reconstruct the original one. The problem is clear now for me , sorry for the question :)